# How to make a value inside of reactive() change, depending on an observeEvent() inside of that reactive()

Tags: r, shiny

Here is the snippet, the question is: how do i make it so `observeEvent()` inside a `reactive()` will change the `a` value?

edit: the real question is, "is it possible without `reactiveValues()`?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn_change", "Change Values"),
  actionButton("btn_print","Print values")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    a <- 1
    data <- reactive({
      observeEvent(input$btn_change, {
        a <- a + 1
      })
      a
    })

  observeEvent(input$btn_print, {
    print(paste("data = ", data()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> EDIT: you modified the question to ask if it is possible without reactiveValues. In this specific case, yes, because an actionbutton's value is incremented by 1 every time you click it. The previous answer with `reactiveValues` that is more widely applicable is shown at the bottom of this post.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("btn_change", "Change Values"),
    actionButton("btn_print","Print values")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  a <- 1

  data <- reactive({
    a + input$btn_change 
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn_print, {
    print(paste("data = ", data()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

> EDIT. modified the solution based on your comments

I think what you are trying to do is increment the value of a reactive every time you click a button. You can achieve that by using a reactiveVal. You can get its value by doing `x()`, and set its value by `x(1)`, where `x` is the name of the reactivevalue.

Note that you can use this reactiveval() in your reactive. Any time you click the button, the reactiveval will increase, and that will trigger the calculation of your reactive.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("btn_change", "Change Values"),
    actionButton("btn_print","Print values")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  a <- 1

  data <- reactiveVal()
  data(a)

  observeEvent(input$btn_change, {
    old_value = data()
    data(old_value+1)
  })

  your_reactive <- reactive({
    data()*2+1
  })


  observeEvent(input$btn_print, {
    print(paste("data = ", your_reactive()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It's just that I have a big `reactive()` in my app, and it will be very painful to change it to something else to make it work.

Comment: button was used as an example, in real app that `reactive()` is a calculation that gives data.frame as an output, and i'm trying to apply filtering from ui side in the middle of the calculations. By the way, I thought that `a <<- a + 1` would work in that case. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that does work. However if multiple users are in your app and they share the same process, you will override the value for all users. So that is not really a wise thing to do. I think the only decent way to solve this is use the reactiveValue.

Comment: If you'll try to use it in the snippet I provided, it won't work. I though of making dummy variable in `server` function and using `makeReactiveBinding()` to give it the value from `observeEvent` and then transfer it to the `reactive()`, but it didn't work in my case. I feel like I spend so much time on soolving this, that I could rewrite that reactive from the scratch already

Comment: I modified the answer, now it should work for your specific case. You can call the reactiveVal in your original reactive. So you should be able to keep your very long reactive intact. Hope this helps!