# Listen to reactives in list

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to add `reactives` to a list and listen to them. I do not understand why in teh code below I do not see any output in `dbg1` while it works in `dgb2`.

The only difference is that `l2` will contain a `reactive` on startup, while `l1` only after the first button press but are otherwise identical.

Any explanation for this?

```r
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   actionButton("add1", "Add to List 1"), 
   actionButton("add2", "Add to List 2"), 
   actionButton("rnd", "Generate Random"),
   verbatimTextOutput("dbg1"),
   verbatimTextOutput("dbg2"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   l1 <- l2 <- list()
   
   observeEvent(input$add1, {
      l1 <<- c(l1, reactive({
         input$rnd
         sample(100, 1)
      }))
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$add2, {
      l2 <<- c(l2, reactive({
         input$rnd
         sample(100, 1)
      }))
   }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
   
   output$dbg1 <- renderPrint(map(l1, ~ .x()))
   output$dbg2 <- renderPrint(map(l2, ~ .x())) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Adter reading the answer from @stefan and the comment from @starja I want to render the issue more precisely.

#### Goal

I want a dynamic container of `reactives`. That is, a dynamically created amount of `reactives`, which do their thing depending on some inputs.

#### Problem

I think in my code the `renderPrint` for `dbg1` is only called on startup. It realizes that there is no `reactive` context (which is indeed only added later) and therefor never recalls it. In the case of `dbg1` it sees at least one reactive and thus comes back. So I guess that I have to make `l1` reactive itself (as pointed out by @stefan)

Comment: I'm not sure what happens here; if you use `browser` in the `observeEvent` you see that also `l1` contains the reactives, but if you use `browser` in `renderPrint` `l1` seems to be empty. Also, if you use `reactlog` you only see the first reactive created in `l2` on startup, but not more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that when `dbg1` first checks `l1`, it does not see any reactive context (which is true). It does, however, not realize that `l1` eventually contains some `reactives` and never "recalls" it.

Thus, I think we have to be more explicit about `l1` by making it reactive itself (inspired by @Stefan):

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   l1 <- l2 <- list()

   r1 <- reactiveVal(list())
   r2 <- reactiveVal(list())
   
   observeEvent(input$add1, {
      r1(c(r1(), reactive({
         input$rnd
         sample(100, 1)
      })))
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$add2, {
      r2(c(r2(), reactive({
         input$rnd
         sample(100, 1)
      })))
      
   }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
   
   output$dbg1 <- renderPrint(map(r1(), ~ .x()))
   output$dbg2 <- renderPrint(map(r2(), ~ .x())) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achive in the end. But following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358135/how-to-make-a-value-inside-of-reactive-change-depending-on-an-observeevent) you could update your lists and have them printed by making use of `reactiveVal` like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add1", "Add to List 1"), 
  actionButton("add2", "Add to List 2"), 
  actionButton("rnd", "Generate Random"),
  verbatimTextOutput("dbg1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("dbg2"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  l1 <- reactiveVal(value = list())
  l2 <- reactiveVal(value = list())
  
  rnd <- eventReactive(input$rnd, {
    sample(100, 1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add1, {
    old_value <- l1()
    l1(c(old_value, rnd()))
  })
  observeEvent(input$add2, {
    old_value <- l2()
    l2(c(old_value, rnd()))
  })
  
  output$dbg1 <- renderPrint(l1())
  output$dbg2 <- renderPrint(l2()) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the pointer. Actuallyyour code adds values to the list only after I have pressed at least once "Generate Random". I want to add reactives with every press of "Add to List" and these reactives should fire (i.e. change the value) whenever I press "Generate Random"